# git workflow for highly audited and changed controlled environments

Tags: git

I work for a large accounting company and we must adhere to strict auditing procedures.  This is one of them.

I need to verify that the code in a developer's feature branch that is being merged into master matches exactly to the code/branch that has been approved on the QA/testing server.  If there are any differences the merge must not happen.

Is there a way to do this using git?  What is a good workflow to facilitate this type of change control?

Things to consider:
We use git and the github flow:

- Master branch is stable and is always deployable.
- Dev maintains a clone of master and creates feature branches from
  that.
- Dev pushes feature branch to QA/UAT server when ever they want.
- When QA/UAT approves dev submits a merge request that a manager then
  merges into master.
- Before the merge is allowed it must match exactly to the code that is
  approved on QA/UAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that with an intermediate repo, manage by a [code review tool like **gerrit**](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/).

You can even couple that with a job scheduler (like Jenkins, as illustrated in [this article](http://blogs.collab.net/teamforge/teamforge-git-gerrit-integration-with-jenkins-ci))

[image: http://blogs.collab.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Git_gerrit_jenkins.png]

In other words, you cannot do it with git alone.
But with git coupled with another tool, and with an intermediate repo managed by this tool and dedicated for quality/code review, it is possible.

Comment: gerrit runs on top of git.  We currently use gitlab (self-hosted) to manage our repos and merges etc.  Would gerrit replace this or can they run side by side?

Comment: @Rodney it (gerrit) can run side-by-side, and plays a different role than the git repo hosting service that is gitlab.